# Vue 2 - How to select the correct <select> option after the data is fetched from db

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue 2 for a small blog project. I have a separate component for post's form and one of the form inputs is a select (for post's category). The select gets populated after the categories are fetched from DB. The component also gets a `post` object from parent component, that is also fetched from the db (see `props: ['post']`).

Here's the code:

```
// HTML
...
<select class="form-control" v-model="post.category_id">
    <option 
        v-for="cat in categories" 
        v-bind:value="cat.id">
        {{ cat.name }}
    </option>
</select>
...

// JS
module.exports = {
    props: ['post', 'url'],
    name: 'postForm',
    created: function() {
        this.syncCats()
    },
    methods: {
        syncCats: function() {
            this.$http.get("/api/categories")
            .then(function(res) {
                this.categories = res.data 
            })
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            categories: {}
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that none of the options is selected by default. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmppf.jpg). But when I open the select I see both categories from my db like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yZA8.jpg).

I want to select the correct (`post.category_id == cat.id`) value by default. How would I do this?

I've tried `<select ... :v-bind:selected="post.category_id == cat.id">` but same happened.

**Edit**

Okay so now I've tried dumping both `post.category_id` and `cat.id` like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Category</label>
  <select class="form-control" v-model="post.category_id">
    <option 
        v-for="cat in categories" 
        :value="cat.id"
        :selected="cat.id == post.category_id">
        {{ cat.name }} {{ cat.id }} {{ post.category_id }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And the result before I select any option is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ci9w.jpg) - only `cat.id` gets printed, `post.category_id` does not. However after I select some option I `post.category_id` appears as well, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MCDb.jpg). Notice how the "1" at the end only appears in 2nd screenshot, after I've selected one of the options, which is the `{{ post.category_id }}`.

This implies that the post is loaded after the categories and that I should somehow reinitialize the select after it's loaded. How would I do this? For reference this is the parent component that fetches the post.

```
<template>
    <span id="home">
        <postForm :post="post" :url="url"></postForm>
    </span>
</template>
<script>
var postForm = require('../forms/post.vue')

module.exports = {
    name: 'postEdit',
    created: function() {
        this.$http.get('api/posts/slug/' + this.$route.params.slug)
        .then(function(response) {
            if(response.status == 200) {
                this.post = response.data
                this.url = "/api/posts/slug/" + response.data.slug
            }
        })
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            post: {},
            url: ""
        }
    },
    components: {
        postForm
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the `selected` attribute on the appropriate `<option>` and adhere to Vue's [one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) paradigm.

You can even add some extra usability sugar by disabling the `<select>` until both the `post` and `categories` are loaded...

```
<select class="form-control" 
        :disabled="!(post.category_id && categories.length)"
        @input="setCategoryId($event.target.value)">
  <option v-for="cat in categories"
          :value="cat.id"
          :selected="cat.id == post.category_id">
    {{cat.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

and

```
methods: {
  setCategoryId(categoryId) {
    this.$emit('input', parseInt(categoryId))
  }
}
```

Then, in the Vue instance / component that includes the above one, simply use

```
<post-form :post="post" :url="url"
           v-model="post.category_id"></post-form>
```

See [Components - Form Input Components using Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) for more information.

JSFiddle demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/1oqjojjx/267/

---

FYI, I'd also initialise `categories` to an array, not an object...

```
data () {
  return {
    categories: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense about initializing to array. However this didn't solve  my issue. I have now tried dumping both `cat.id` and `post.category_id` in all of the select names and it turns out only `cat.id` gets printed out until I select one of the options, then the `post.category_id` gets printed out as well. So I'm pretty sure I have to somehow reinit the select after post get fetched. How would I do this?

Comment: @devk Ah, I think this plays in to the Vue.js principal of [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). You probably shouldn't be trying to modify the `category_id` on `post`. Try using my answer and omitting `v-model`. I'll make some updates to illustrate

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me and helping me out :). I'll try the updated answer in the evening when I'm home.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like following:

```
methods: {
    syncCats: function() {
        this.$http.get("/api/categories")
        .then(function(res) {
            this.categories = res.data 
            if(!this.post.category_id) { 
               this.post.category_id = this.categories[0].id
            }
        })
    }
},
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as there won't be a `categories[0]` when the component first renders. Also, where is the documentation for `v-init`? Can't see it anywhere

Comment: But I don't want to override `post.category_id`. It already has a value (this is an edit form).

Comment: if `post.category_id` already has an value it should be by default selected, if you are using this in both create and edit case, than you can assign a value to `this.post.category_id` when it is undefined, and otherwise use it as it is. I will update this in answer. is it possible for you to create a fiddle for this.

Comment: It does already have a value. I've updated the question with some more info. The problem is that categories get fetched, then select initializes and then post gets fetched, which apparently doesn't reinitialize the select again. I've posted 2 screenshots that show really weird behavior - the `post.category_id` only show after I select one of the options.

Comment: This violates the [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) paradigm between components

Comment: @Phil you are absolutely right and same is happening when OP is modifying the same via select input.

Comment: @Phil Vue is completely new for me. What's a good workaround for this? The idea behind my implementation is that both `edit.vue` and `new.vue` components can reuse the same `postForm.vue` form component. I would like to keep it this way.